# How to make an empty DateTime field in an update trigger?

Tags: trigger, datetime, field-update, update, updaterecord

I want my DateTime field (Due_Date__c) in the custom object to be empty once I update the record. However, it's not changing to null when I update the record.

```
public class TestObject2Class {
  public static void TATDueDate(List<TestObject2__c> li){

      
        for(TestObject2__c gfDea : li){           
            if (gfDea.Health_Status__c == 'Good'){
                gfDea.Due_Date__c= null;
            } else if (gfDea.Health_Status__c != null){
                if(gfDea.Health_Status__c == 'For checking'){
                    if(gfDea.Clean__c == true){
                        gfDea.Due_Date__c= Date.newInstance(1991, 05, 25);
                    } else if(gfDea.isOkay__c == false){
                        gfDea.Due_Date__c= Date.newInstance(1991, 05, 20);
                    }
                }              
            }           
        }       
    }
}
trigger TestObject2Trigger on TestObject2__c (before update) {
    
    if (trigger.isUpdate){
        if (trigger.isBefore){
            TestObject2Class.TATDueDate(trigger.new);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason could be you are populating that field either through to some flow/Process builder/trigger/workflow. So the changes are getting overridden.

Comment: This one is actually working now after a few refresh. This code is just a test. However, the code that I am writing with almost the same code is not updating. I think it's not possible that it will get overriden because I am using a newly created account,

Comment: I have edited the code above. That's the one which is not working. Also I have 8 values in Health_Status__c  which is a picklist field.

Comment: Hi, this is closed now. The problem is just the wrong value in the picklist field. My apologies.. but thank you